# How can i get the correct answer to show at the location of correct answer

Tags: android

I am creating a quiz game which is working fine,but the problem am encountering is that whenever the user selects the correct answer, its shows it as wrong answer,meanwhile it's the correct answer, it's turns out the correct answer is not at the correct location.

Here is my code so far, any ideas how i can fix this.

```
public class RiddleGuessActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        TextView riddleQuestionTextView;
        Button btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btnContinue, btnOk;

        ArrayList<String> riddles = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> answers = new ArrayList<>();
        int locationOfCorrectAnswers = 0,incorrectAnswers = 0;
        ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<>();
        LinearLayout gameOverLayout;
        LinearLayout buttonLayout;
        RelativeLayout resultLayout;
        TextView timerTextView;
        TextView answerTextView;
        TextView levelTextView, scoreTextView;
        TextView gameOverTextView;
        int levelCounter = 1, scoreCounter, riddleCounter = 0;

        public void chosenRiddle (View view) {

            if (view.getTag().toString().equals(Integer.toString(locationOfCorrectAnswers))) {

                //Toast.makeText(RiddleGuessActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                levelCounter++;
                scoreCounter+=60;
                riddleCounter++;
                levelTextView.setText(String.valueOf(levelCounter));
                scoreTextView.setText(String.valueOf(scoreCounter));

                result();

            }else {

                Toast.makeText(RiddleGuessActivity.this, "Wrong, It was " +
                        answers.get(riddleCounter), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                gameOver();
            }
        }

        public void generateRiddles () {

            riddles.add("I kiss my mother before i die. What am i ?");
            riddles.add("It is greater than God and more evil than the devil. The poor have it, the rich need it and if you eat it you'll die. What am i ?");
            riddles.add("It walks on four legs in the morning, two legs at noon and three legs in the evening. What am i ?");
            riddles.add("I am the beginning of the end, and the end of time and space. I am essential to creation and i surround everyplace. What am i ?");
            riddles.add("What always runs but never walks, often murmurs, never talks, has a bed but never sleeps, has a mouth but never eats. What am i ?");
            riddles.add("At night they come without being fetched, By day they are lost without being stolen. What am i ?");
            riddles.add("The one who makes it, sells it. The one who buys it, never uses it. The one that uses it never knows that he's using it. What am i ?");
            riddles.add("The more you have of it, the less you see. What am i ?");
            riddles.add("I am always hungry, i must be fed, the finger i touch will soon turn red. What am i ?");
            riddles.add("If you break me, i do not stop working, if you touch me, i may snared, if you lose me, nothing will matter. What am i ?");

            answers.add("Matches");
            answers.add("Nothing");
            answers.add("Man");
            answers.add("Letter E");
            answers.add("River");
            answers.add("The Stars");
            answers.add("A Coffin");
            answers.add("Darkness");
            answers.add("Fire");
            answers.add("Heart");
            answers.add("The Moon");
            answers.add("Food");
            answers.add("Love");
            answers.add("Mouth");
            answers.add("Money");

            Random random = new Random();

            riddleQuestionTextView.setText(riddles.get(riddleCounter));

            locationOfCorrectAnswers = random.nextInt(4);

            options.clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

                if (i == locationOfCorrectAnswers &&
                        !options.contains(answers.get(riddleCounter))) {

                    options.add(answers.get(riddleCounter));

                }else {

                    incorrectAnswers = random.nextInt(answers.size());

                    while (incorrectAnswers == riddleCounter) {

                        incorrectAnswers = random.nextInt(answers.size());
                    }

                    if(!options.contains(answers.get(incorrectAnswers)))
                        options.add(answers.get(incorrectAnswers));
                    else --i;

                }

            }

            btn1.setText(options.get(0));
            btn2.setText(options.get(1));
            btn3.setText(options.get(2));
            btn4.setText(options.get(3));
        }
```

Comment: It would be great if you could [edit] to reduce this code to show a [mcve] as well as explain the logic behind what you are trying to do with these counters and location variables.

Comment: It's minimal yes, but not complete or verifiable

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing an onCreate method??

Anyways, I suggest you add the `correctAnswer` followed by the incorrect `options`. Basically, forget random numbers and while loops.

Then `Collections.shuffle()` the list.

Then scan the list for the location of the correct answer.

Comment: how do i make it complete or verifiable